# Referring to oneself in first vs. third person in online profiles

Tags: style

Suppose I am writing a post/blog, how should I mention myself?

For example,

> Ray Wenderlich (Site Admin)
>
> Ray is an indie software developer currently focusing on iPhone and iPad development. He’s the founder of a small iPhone development studio called Razware.

Now another example from [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/09/06/how-to-write-an-effective-about-me-page/). They insist to write like this:

> My name is Ray Wenderlich. I am an indie software developer currently focusing on iPhone and iPad development. I am the founder of a small iPhone Dev. Studio Razware.

I have also observed both ways of writing on many Google+ and Facebook profiles. Some write about themselves in first person, others in third.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a question about English, it seems to me more a question for programmers.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a matter of style whether you want your "profile" to look as if it's written by you, or by someone else.

Follow your own inclination unless you're doing it in a context where someone else (the site, your employer, etc.) sets the rules. In which case do what they say.

I'd be surprised if any Writers.SE members have refered to themselves as *He* in their profiles. It seems a bit silly to do that if there's *no* possibility that someone else wrote the profile. But I imagine people sometimes do this to give the impression they're so busy they don't have time to do the write-up themselves, but so important someone else will do it for them.

Comment: @pavium: I've no opinion on the authorship of Mr Desai's profile as linked by OP. Since it *could reasonably* have been written by "a loyal and adoring minion", it's not inherently silly for it to be in the third person, even if in fact Mr Desai wrote it himself. I only said what I did in relation to ELU profiles, since it's *unreasonable* to suppose they could be written by anyone other than the member himself.

Answer (score 6):

I think a major difference is: do you want to give the reader the sense that **you are speaking to him**, or do you want to give him the sense that **he is reading about you**?

First person can feel more personal, more informal, as if an actual person is standing in front of the reader - "Hi, I'm Ray!". Third person is a description of the profile owner - generally aiming for a neutral, factual/descriptive tone ("Ray is an experienced software developer") that can feel more professional and matter-of-fact. Sometimes, this can be humorously subverted ("Ray's core competencies include vast expertise in software developement and ingenious placement of whoopie cushions when his co-workers aren't looking").

So in general, first-person is great for feeling like a personal introduction; third-person is great for a straightforward, professional description of yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using third person offers the benefit, that the profile can be used by other persons referring to you.

E. g. you wrote a book and a newspaper/magazine is writing a review, then they also want to add a profile of the author. If your online profile is written in third person, they can just copy-paste it (with your approval). Some authors have special sections on their home pages for this press stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it depends on whether you are trying to be personable or professional. If you want to have the reader feel that they are reading comments directly from you, in a personal manner, then the first person would be a better approach. If your goal is to present your skills and experiences in a professional manner, as if you were dealing with a client, then third person would be better.

Standback gave a [very good response](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/referring-to-oneself-in-first-vs-third-person-in-online-profiles/3389#3389) that basically takes this same approach.

Answer (score 0):

The blurb on the dust jacket of a book that describes the author is usually in the third person, even if it was written by the author himself.

Answer (score 0):

Third person.

A biography is an objective look at the person's life.

First person can have overtones of subjective opinions.